# Google chart : Container is not defined when html changes

Tags: html, angularjs, api

I'm getting the error "Container is not defined" after I click on a different page while the api is loading.

I'm sure that my

var chartTwo = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchartDue'))

is working because the error doesn't pop up if I just wait on the same page until everything is loaded.

I believe the cause of this error is that my chart div is no longer there when my template changes while api is running in the background (basically html and apis are asynchronous). =(

Anyone got any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm guys, I used  if (angular.element('#donutchartId').length) {} to check if the div exist before the charts get drawn and it worked